# How to pass a ruby hash as a commandline option?

Tags: ruby, slim-lang

I'm using slimrb, which has an option called `attr_list_delims` that expects a hash as the value in the format of:

```
{'(' => ')', '[' => ']', '{' => '}'}
```

I need to change that to just

```
{'(' => ')', '[' => ']'}
```

I'm not familiar with ruby, is this even possible to pass as a commandline argument?

Wrapping the entire thing in double quotes didn't seem to work

Comment: Command-line parameters are strings. I suppose you could eval it.

Comment: I don't think that option was meant to be used from command line. Can you point to where that is documented?

Comment: is that something that would have to be done on the project maintainer's end?

Comment: @nicooga It's on the github repo's readme. https://github.com/slim-template/slim search for attr_list_delims.  You're probably right, and that would suck because I really wanted to use slim for a project with gulp, and would have to use slimrb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/slim-template/slim#slim-command-slimrb), it looks like you should be able to do it using the `--option` flag:

> ```
> $ slimrb --help
> Usage: slimrb [options]
>   -o, --option name=code           Set slim option
> ```

To me, the word "code" there implies that you can use any Ruby expression you want. If that is indeed correct, you could use it like this:

```
slimrb --option attr_list_delims="{'(' => ')', '[' => ']'}"
```

A quick peak at [the source code](https://github.com/slim-template/slim/blob/f2cdb1ddd757db3e4d849959424011579a53d285/lib/slim/command.rb#L67) seems to confirm that assumption:

```
opts.on('-o', '--option name=code', String, 'Set slim option') do |str|
  parts = str.split('=', 2)
  Engine.default_options[parts.first.gsub(/\A:/, '').to_sym] = eval(parts.last)
end
```

Note that this feature is specific to `slimrb`, not to Ruby in general.

Comment: thank you! this did work, now I'm running into a different issue with the gulp-slim pacakge needlessly escaping thing '\' and ''' but I should probably start a separate question for that :)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a little less than ideal and not slim-specific, but you could pass it as JSON and use `JSON.parse`:

```
# test.rb
require 'json'
puts JSON.parse(ARGV[0])
```

Then executing it with a parameter that is a string representation of a JSON-ified hash will produce the expected result:

```
ccashwell:~/dev/fun (master) ✗ ruby test.rb '{"(": ")", "[": "]"}'
{"("=>")", "["=>"]"}
```